# How to count elements in group, when the element can be assigned to many groups

Tags: hive, bigdata

Given the following data: (id: **int**, group:  **string**)

```
+---------+-----------+
| id      | group     | 
+---------+-----------+
| 1       | 'a,b,c'   |
| 2       | 'a'       |
| 3       | 'a,c'     |
+---------+-----------+
```

I want to get a participant count of each group. The result should be:

```
+---------+--------+
| group   | count  | 
+---------+--------+
| a       | 3      |
| b       | 1      |
| c       | 2      |
+---------+--------+
```

How can I achieve it? How the query should look like? I have tried with split() function but without any results :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```sql
select
   main.group,
   count(1)
from
   (
   select
       explode(split(group, ",")) as group
   from
       main
   ) main
group by
   main.group
```

If your query is more complex than the sample you provided, you might also like to read about `lateral view`.

Ref. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF

Comment: Thanks for lateral view!